# Companies that currently manufacture aircraft with center stick controls?

Tags: aircraft-design, flight-controls, cockpit

I was wondering if any general aviation manufacturers currently produce center stick control aircraft.  (Not including LSA, Sailplanes, Helicopters). I'm asking about four+ place aircraft other than the diamond da40.

Comment: I know first-hand that the Falke SF25 Motorglider -- a single-engined light aircraft with an optimal glide ratio of ~25:1 -- contains a single, centre-stick. Also, only P1 gets a "six pack" of instruments, P2 looks at the radios!

Comment: This question, by definition, is off-topic as too broad. It is asking for a list of aircraft. At the time I am writing this comment, there are two answers and both are correct. Both list at least one aircraft "still in production" which uses a center stick control. Which answer should be marked/mark-able as 'correct'? VtC as too broad, unless you can edit it to be specifically and completely answerable in a single answer.

Comment: When I edited the title I was thinking of looking at the types of planes that use center stick and why, but that is pretty close to [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/999/1696).

Comment: Asking for companies that make these aircraft isn't much better, and CGCampbell's comment still applies.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the lancair airplanes have it but those are kit built so Im not sure if you can count them as true production planes.

- Vans aircraft
- Most Variants of the Piper Cub like planes that are still made
- Extra Aircraft
- Pipistril Aircraft
- Czech Sport (formally Piper Sport)

Its worth noting that Cessna did recently have a run trying to make the "Sky Catcher" which was quickly discontinued but center stick none the less.

A lot of light sport airplane and aerobatic planes tend to have center sticks.

Comment: Skycatcher wasnt actually a stick, more a single-bar yoke. Good list otherwise!

Comment: @egid, I did notice that but I have never flown one so I was not sure exactly how it worked although it does look like a stick ;)

Comment: Good pic of the SkyCatcher bar:
http://www.jseagle.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/162.jpg