# What’s this on the J-10 fighter?

Tags: feature-identification, chengdu-j-10

What's this on the J-10 fighter?

> [image]
> Source: [wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:PLAAF_J-10B_with_PL-12_and_PL-8B_at_ZhuHai_Air_Show_2018.jpg)

Comment: Related:  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/31799/60584

Answer (score 5):

Air to air refueling probe.

Here is a youtube:

And for when that youtube goes away, a screencap of that:
[image: J-10 refuel video]

Answer (score 4):

That looks like an in-flight refueling probe.